# Evolution plugin for Exchange not showing contacts

Tags: sync, evolution, contacts, ms-exchange

I was attempting to sync my contacts & calendar from outlook.com. Did some searching around and ran into 2 options, Evolution & Thunderbird.
Evolution has a really nice look and feel, and like to use that. I installed the evolution plugin for MS Exchange using the following sudo command:

```
 sudo apt-get install evolution-ews
```

I was able to add an account successfully.

Currently Calendars are in Sync. But my contacts do not show up in the Contacts Pane. This is what I see in Contacts (See image).
I explored around a bit, and I noticed that in Thunderbird it shows the contacts (using - Ericsson/exchangecalendar). But for it to show up in Thunderbird using that plugin, during configuration - I had to select the root of Contacts (Selecting any of the Listed Address Books wouldn't populate it).

See below:
[image]

In Evolution, Selecting the numerous AddressBooks listed from my account does not populate the default contacts list. I do not see any other options.
What have I missed? How can I view the contacts?

Comment: Our IT has addresses in a separate ldap server address. It does not come auto with exchange calendar connection.

Comment: Did not get  the context.